# PDO SQLSTATE[07002]:COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, float

Estou com problemas para fazer um decremento no sql com pdo. estou recebendo o seguinte erro

> SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

código

```
<?php
ob_start();
include'../../classes/config.php';
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['ID'];

$creditosplayer = (float)$_POST["creditos"];


try {
  $pdo = new PDO($pdoconnection, $user, $pass);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE [omegashop].[dbo].[cad_users] SET                         [creditos] = :creditosplayer WHERE [userid] = :user");
  $query->bindValue(':creditosplayer', $creditosplayer);
  $query->execute();

  echo 1;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Como deve ser o parâmetro correto para o tipo float ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que você esqueceu de definir o valor para `:user`
Está setando somente o valor para `:creditosplayer` em:

> `$query->bindValue(':creditosplayer', $creditosplayer);`

Faça:

> `$query->bindValue(':creditosplayer', $creditosplayer);`
>
> `$query->bindValue(':user', $username);`

Comment: puts tinha me esquecido desse detalhe hehe muito obriado